# Problems with "Invalid allocation size"

Tags: debugging, memory-management, hash

I'm trying to implement the SuperFastHash algo I got from here;
http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/hash.html

Here is my .h and .cpp
SuperFastHash.h

```
#ifndef SUPER_FAST_HASH
#define SUPER_FAST_HASH

// #include "pstdint.h" /* Replace with <stdint.h> if appropriate */
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cstddef>

#undef get16bits
#if (defined(__GNUC__) && defined(__i386__)) || defined(__WATCOMC__) \
  || defined(_MSC_VER) || defined (__BORLANDC__) || defined (__TURBOC__)
#define get16bits(d) (*((const uint16_t *) (d)))
#endif

#if !defined (get16bits)
#define get16bits(d) ((((uint32_t)(((const uint8_t *)(d))[1])) << 8)\
                       +(uint32_t)(((const uint8_t *)(d))[0]) )
#endif

uint32_t SuperFastHash (const char * data, int len);

#endif
```

And here is my .cpp

```
#include "SuperFastHash.h"

uint32_t SuperFastHash (const char * data, int len) {

    uint32_t hash = len, tmp;
    int rem = 0;

    if (len <= 0 || data == NULL) return 0;

    rem = len & 3;
    len >>= 2;

    /* Main loop */
    for (;len > 0; len--) {
        hash  += get16bits (data);
        tmp    = (get16bits (data+2) << 11) ^ hash;
        hash   = (hash << 16) ^ tmp;
        data  += 2*sizeof (uint16_t);
        hash  += hash >> 11;
    }

    /* Handle end cases */
    switch (rem) {
        case 3: hash += get16bits (data);
                hash ^= hash << 16;
                hash ^= ((signed char)data[sizeof (uint16_t)]) << 18;
                hash += hash >> 11;
                break;
        case 2: hash += get16bits (data);
                hash ^= hash << 11;
                hash += hash >> 17;
                break;
        case 1: hash += (signed char)*data;
                hash ^= hash << 10;
                hash += hash >> 1;
    }

    /* Force "avalanching" of final 127 bits */
    hash ^= hash << 3;
    hash += hash >> 5;
    hash ^= hash << 4;
    hash += hash >> 17;
    hash ^= hash << 25;
    hash += hash >> 6;

    return hash;
}
```

The problem is that when I run this line it seems to crash:
uint32_t entityHashId = SuperFastHash(entityname.c_str(), strlen(entityname.c_str()));

(entityname is a const std::string& entityname)

It thorws this error message:
Debug Error
{Path to .exe file}
Invalid allocation size: 4294967295 bytes.
(Press Retry to debug the application)
[Abort] [Retry] [Ignore]

Comment: If there is not enough information here to answer the problem please let me know. Felt it was a bit to much to dump the whole source here.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: You cannot (obv) allocate memory with a negative size.

After 1 hour of debugging and not finding out what was wrong it seems that deep inside one of our libs there was a abs(x) * -1.. Which kinda defeated the purpose.

[image]

Comment: I was about to comment to replace all the ints used for indexes and sizes to some unsigned type, preferrably size_t.